# Java programming in Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android-studio-3.0

How can I write a Java program in Android Studio version 3.1? 
Can I import any java project from eclipse to Android Studio?

Comment: Probably a good place to start -> https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, i started an Android project in Eclipse and finally switched to Android Studio. You can import your Java Project to Android Studio. AS migrate a lot of stuff for you like generating gradle files and more.

**Just export your Eclipse Java project as archive (`.zip`) and import it to Android Studio.**

You will recognize that you have to change some things in your source code but if this is done you will be happy.

Finally, i have to say that it was a good idea to switch to Android Studio in Android application development because AS is the recommended IDE by Google (not surprising) and it handles a lot of things for you.